# Multimap with HashMultiset for values

Tags: java, collections, guava, multimap

I'm trying to have a (hash-based) Multimap with a (hash-based) Multiset of values for each key. See the example:

```
Multimap<Object, Object> mmap = Multimaps.newMultimap(
    Maps.<Object, Collection<Object>>newHashMap(), 
    new Supplier<Collection<Object>>() {
  public Collection<Object> get() {
    return HashMultiset.create();
  }
});
mmap.put("1", "2");
```

But then,

```
System.out.println(mmap.get("1") instanceof Multiset<?>); 
//false, the returned collection is not a HashMultiset,
//but a (private) WrappedCollection
```

So it seems I cannot access the multiset I created? I wanted to be able to return that, as a Multiset (wrapped in Multisets.unmodifiableMultiset()). I don't want to copy it into a new Multiset each time either. Do I have any other option than switching back to `Map<K, Multiset<V>>` and adding in my code the complexity that `Multimap` meant to eliminate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid this doesn't seem to be possible. You should file a feature request. I have a sneaking suspicion those crafty Google folks have a nifty kind of a Multimap that they could potentially release that might potentially help you.

Comment: Oh well, that's what I suspected, thanks anyway. I'm not exactly sure what feature to ask for (since there is always the danger of getting it :)). PS: you are so secretive at times!

Comment: I'd like this too. No chance it's happened in the last ≳4 years?

Comment: Alas, no, we have lost faith in the particular solution we formerly thought we might release.

Answer (score 0):

The [Multimap interface](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) only specifies that `get(K)` return a `Collection<V>`. I think it would be poor design for your code to depend or assume anything else.

Can you expand a little bit more on what you are trying to do here? Seems like there should be an easier way to accomplish it.

Comment: The short version of the question is: "I just want a multimap where I can see the values through the Multiset API, not the Collection API".